# Does the order of -l and -L options in the GNU linker matter?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, binutils

The `-l` option tells the linker to search the libraries in the standard dirs.
And with `-L`, we can specify our own library directories for searching.

Question: Does the sequence of order matters for the `-L` option too, like it does for the `-l` w.r.t the linker?

This link: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html doesn't say much about the sequence of `-L`.

**EDIT**
Also,

> Directories specified on the command
>   line are searched before the default
>   directories

is from the man page (as pointed by Dmitry), does this mean that even if I specify the order like:

```
gcc -lm hello.c -Lx
```

still the directory specified with `-L` will be given preference first?

Comment: `still the library specified with -L`... : -L does _not_ specify a library (it specifies search directories)

Comment: @sehe thanks, that was a typo (now I've edited), I haven't yet received an answer to my second question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the order of `-L` options matters - just like `-l` and `-I` options.

From `man ld`

> **-Lsearchdir**
>   **--library-path=searchdir**
>
> Add path searchdir to the list of paths that ld will search for archive libraries and ld control scripts.   You  may  use         this  option  any  number of times.  The directories are searched in the order in which they are specified on the command           line.  Directories specified on the command line are searched before the default directories.  All -L  options  apply  to           all -l options, regardless of the order in which the options appear.

<del>[GCC documentations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and more specifically [Linking Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) will be useful for you</del>

**Edit**
Sorry, indeed I missed to check the link you've given. "man ld" can just be written in the console.

**Edit2**
I made a simple test putting `-l` before `-L` options and it shows no difference comparing to `-L` before `-l`

So answering your second question, this

```
gcc -lm hello.c -Lx
```

is equal to this

```
gcc -Lx -lm hello.c
```

libm is searched first in directory x/ in both tests.

Note though that putting `-l<lib>` before source files is a bad practice, that may lead to undefined references when linking. This is the correct way

```
gcc hello.c -Lx -lm
```

Comment: Thanks, that must be documented somewhere, I can't find it, if you have a link which confirms the thing, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Grateful to you :hattip: I did search Google before asking here, with the keywords 'man ld' and the second link I got was: http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux, I prefer _die.net_ w.r.t man pages, but this time I mistook 'ld-linux' for 'ld'. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Did you not click the link I posted in my first post? Your second link is the same. And I do follow the GNU's official online docs. Thanks for bothering :)

Comment: @Dmitry please see the edit in my first post too and see if you can comment on it?

Comment: @Dmitry thanks very much, so it means that the used specified locations are searched first as compared to standard directories, irrespective of the placement order.

Comment: So -L indicates the library dir, and -l indicates the library to use. In this case, the file libm.a should be in the dir ./x ?

Comment: @qed Yes, the library file (.a or .so) should be in directory x/ according to given examples. 

Note that libm.a is just a random library name in this example, don't get confused with system math library libm.so/.a