# AutoConf - AC_CHECK_LIB dealing with duplicate libraries

Tags: duplicates, libraries, conflict, autoconf

Assume I have `/foo/X.a` and `/foo/X.dylib`, and `LDFLAGS=-L/foo`. What will `AC_CHECK_LIB` do? Is `.dylib` guaranteed to take precedence over `.a`? Vice versa? Random?

Assume I have `/foo/Y.a` and `/bar/Y.a`, and `LDFLAGS=-L/foo:/bar`? What will happen then?

Is there some way to manually establish precedence?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not addressed by `autoconf`. In the case that you have both `/foo/X.a` and `/foo/X.dylib`, the `configure` script will simply attempt to link with `libX` and will do whatever your toolchain does. If your linker uses `X.a`, then the `configure` script will do its tests using `X.a`. If your linker uses `X.dylib`, then the `configure` script will use that. The way to establish precedence will therefore depend on your toolchain (e.g. perhaps you can add `-Bstatic` to `LDFLAGS`).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way to manually establish precedence?

*You* are manually establishing [precedence of library search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817269/does-the-order-of-l-and-l-options-in-the-gnu-linker-matter) by using the `-L` option.

> Also what if I have /foo/Y.a and /bar/Y.a, and LDFLAGS=-L/foo:/bar
>   What will happen then?

It will look in the directory `/foo:/bar` before the default library paths.  It's not clear from your question if `Y.a` is actually supposed to be linked to anything.

> What will AC_CHECK_LIB do? Is .dylib guaranteed to take precedence over .a? Vice versa? Random?

It won't be random, but will be influenced by other options given to `configure` (e.g. `LDFLAGS`, `--disable-shared`, etc.).  All `AC_CHECK_LIB` does is plop in the name of the selected function into a `main` function (with appropriate libraries added) and see if it links.