# Compile a C program in Linux using shared library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I am trying to compile a simple C program in Linux with a shared library.

I have all together in the same folder the following files:

**mymain.c**

```
 #include "myclib.h"
 int main() {
   func();
   return 0;
}
```

**myclib.h**

```
 void func();
```

**myclib.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func() {

   printf("hello world!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");

}
```

Then I followed these steps:

- `gcc -c fPIC myclib.c` (create memoryaddress independent objectfile)

  which produces: myclib.o
- `gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmyclib.so myclib.o` (create shared library)
- `gcc -c mymain.c` (creates an object file out of main.c)

So far so good - then I have the following files ready:

- main.o
- libmyclib.so

So I try to create a program out of this syntax:

`gcc -o program -lmyclib -L. mymain.o`

(I guess the prefix lib from libmyclib should be replaced with an l?)

But I get the error message from the gc-compiler:

```
 *mymain.o: In function `main':
 mymain.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `func'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*
```

I have also tested this syntax:

`gcc -o program mymain.c -L -lmyclib -Wl,-rpath,.`

Then I get the following error:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmyclib.so
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong in these two implementations?
How do I compile this program to an executable using shared library?

Comment: Change `gcc -o program -lmyclib -L. mymain.o` to `gcc -o program mymain.o -lmyclib -L.`

Comment: @PaulR The `-k` options need to go last.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I don't think so (assuming you mean `-L` ?) - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817269/does-the-order-of-l-and-l-options-in-the-gnu-linker-matter

Comment: @PaulR I meant `-l`; sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @FUZxxl: indeed - the main point though was that the order of the `-L` and `-l` options don't matter - see the answer I linked to. The only thing that matters is the order of the object files and libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place `-l` options on the end of linker invocation command line:

```
gcc -o program -L. mymain.o -lmyclib
```

Comment: thanks it works!!! but now when I execute program with ./program I get the error message:  **error while loading shared libraries: libmyclib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory** . But I will accept this answer in a couples of minutes :-)

Comment: Wouldn't you need to change LD_PRELOAD to load a shared object located outside the predefined directories?

Comment: yes - i guess it looks in usr/lib or something?