# Error in testing Paillier library: (.text+0x72): undefined reference to

Tags: c, ruby, rake, paillier

I am trying to use this Paillier libray http://acsc.cs.utexas.edu/libpaillier/ , it will be just a part of some UDF that i m trying to make for Mysql server

This a part from my Rakefile:

```
task :compile do
  puts 'Compiling the encryption / decryption program.'
  system("gcc -L/usr/local/lib/ -I/usr/local/include/ -lgmp -lpaillier #{config[:exec_file]}.c -o #{config[:exec_file]}")
end
```

However, i m geeting this error:

```
cipher.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `paillier_get_rand_devurandom'
cipher.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `paillier_keygen'
cipher.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `paillier_pubkey_to_hex'
cipher.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `paillier_prvkey_to_hex'
cipher.c:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `paillier_freepubkey'
cipher.c:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `paillier_freeprvkey'
/tmp/ccMPIY0I.o: In function `getKey':
```

So please, any one knows where the problem is?

Ps: `exec_file` is a the C file where I am including `paillier.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a problem in the order of arguments in your gcc call.
The libraries should be written after the source file and output file:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib/ -I/usr/local/include/ #{config[:exec_file]}.c -o #{config[:exec_file]} -lgmp -lpaillier
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817269/does-the-order-of-l-and-l-options-in-the-gnu-linker-matter).

Comment: thanx that worked perfectly for me i ve changed the order of the source file and the lib like this gcc  #{config[:exec_file]}.c -o #{config[:exec_file]} -lgmp -lpaillier -L/usr/local/lib/ -I/usr/local/include/ , apparently putting -l<lib> before source files is a bad practice, that may lead to undefined references when linking.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to develop an intuition for how gcc requires its arguments. Nice to hear it links now.

Comment: yup, thanx for that